# Form values are overwritten after change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that shows up when each row in a table is double clicked. The values of this form can be updated and the form should be submitted with all row changes. But each time I double click on a row and edit the values of that form for that row, the previous values I had changed get overwritten. In order to work around this, I tried adding all the changes to a map with the row id as the key and the values of the form as the value. But the form still won't update with the new values. Here is a fiddle to demonstrate what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/4fr3edk7/2/

If I double click on the row that says "Adam Smith" and change that name to John Doe, when I double click on the second row and then double Click on "Adam Smith" again, it should say "John" on the first textbox and "Doe" on the second one. But the new value never seems to save.

This code snippet loops through each key, then loops through each value of that key:

```
for(var i = 0; i<key.length; i++){
    var getval = globalchanges[key[i]];
  for(var k=0; k<getval.length; k++){
        $("#input1").val(getval[0]);
      $("#input2").val(getval[1]);
  }
 }
```

How can I get the new changes to save? (The table rows don't have to show the changes, just the textbox values). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as mentioned by @Taplar you are binding the click event multiple times. Your approach is close enough, the idea of storing the changes is valid. You should have 2 functions, store the changes on button click and the second one to retrieve the changes by id.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fr3edk7/3/)

This function will get the values of the form and will store in on a global object

```
function setMap(id){
    var firstrow =  $("#input1").val();
    var secondrow = $("#input2").val();
    globalchanges[id] = [firstrow,secondrow];
}
```

This other function will check if the global object has values for the passed id, if not, it will use the values on the row

```
function getMap(id, tr){
    if(globalchanges[id] != undefined && globalchanges[id].length == 2){
        $("#input1").val(globalchanges[id][0]);
        $("#input2").val(globalchanges[id][1]);
    }
    else{
        $("#input1").val($(tr).find('td').eq(1).text());
        $("#input2").val($(tr).find('td').eq(2).text());    
    }
}
```

Please note there are also changes on the dbclick and click events, they should be separated

```
$("#table tr").dblclick(function(){
    $("#txtbox-wrapper").css({"display" : "block"});
    var id = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
    $('#id').val(id);
    getMap(id,this);
});
$("#savebtn").click(function(){
    var id = $('#id').val();
    setMap(id);
});
```

And that we added and additional input to store the id on the form.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to rethink your logic because of this part

```
$("#table tr").dblclick(function(){
   $("#txtbox-wrapper").css({"display" : "block"});
    var id = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();

    $("#input1").val($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
    $("#input2").val($(this).find('td').eq(2).text());

    $("#savebtn").click(function(){
      addToMap(id);
    });
});
```

-Every time- you double click a table row you are adding a new click binding to the savebtn element.  This means if you double click both rows, when you click that button it will execute addToMap for both ids.  You may have other issues with your logic relying on only two other inputs for multiple rows, but this double/triple/+ binding is going to bite you.

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes required in your logic as well as implementation.

1: Do not bind save event inside row click.
2: You are selecting the value in row double click event from td element. You need to update this element to keep your logic working
3: Keep track of which row is getting updated.

Updated Code

```
 var globalchanges = {};
 var rowSelected = null;


 $("#table tr").dblclick(function() {
   $("#txtbox-wrapper").css({
     "display": "block"
   });
   rowSelected = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
   $("#input1").val($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
   $("#input2").val($(this).find('td').eq(2).text());
 });

 $("#savebtn").click(function() {
   addToMap(rowSelected);
 });

 function addToMap(row) {
   var array = [];
   var changes = {};
   var firstrow = $("#input1").val();
   var secondrow = $("#input2").val();
   array.push(firstrow, secondrow);
   globalchanges[row] = array;
   makeChanges(row);
 }



 function makeChanges(row) {

   var key = Object.keys(globalchanges);

   console.log(key);

   $("#table tr td").each(function(k, v) {
     if ($(v).text() == key) {
       $(v).next().html(globalchanges[row][0]);
       $(v).next().next().html(globalchanges[row][1]);
       globalchanges = {};
     }
   });


 }
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yudLxsgu/